# How does Word2Vec ensure that antonyms will be far apart in the vector space

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

Broadly speaking the training of word2vec is a process in which words that are often in the same context are clustered together in the vector space.
We start by randomly shuffling the words on the plane and then with each iteration more and more clusters form. 
I think I understood this but how can we assure that the words that are antonyms or rarely appear in the same context don't end up in clusters that are close by?  Also how can we know that words that are more irrelevant are farther away than word that are less irrelevant.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked on datascience.SE.

Comment: The topic is one of programming *tools*; `word2vec` reliability certainly falls under that category for me.  I agree that the question would be better put to datascience.SE, but I think it's not entirely off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate somewhat on Novak's response:

You seem to regard `word2vec` as a tool to evaluate semantic *meaning*.  Although much of the result is correlated with meaning, that is *not* the functionality of `word2vec`.  Rather, it indicates contextual correlation, which is (somewhat loosely) regarded as "relevance".

When this "relevance" is applied to certain problems, *especially* when multiple "relevance" hits are required to support a reportable result, *then* the overall effect is often useful to the problem at hand.

For your case, note that a word and its antonym will often appear near one another, for literary contrast or other emphasis.  As such, they are contextually *quite* relevant to one another.  Unless you have some pre-processing that can identify and appropriately alter various forms of negation, you will see such pairs often in your vectorization -- as is appropriate to the tool.

Answer (score 5):

We can't. That is the problem of word2vec. We cannot differentiate between negation synonym and antonyms because those words, as you said, often appear in the same context.